# Java Spring @ResponseBody return XML with produce attribute

Tags: java, spring, http, model-view-controller

Recently, I'm trying to get the xml file under the resources file. Then all the questions come out.
I read so many articles say something like:

> @ResponseBody tells a controller that the object returned is
> automatically serialized into JSON and passed back into the
> HttpResponse object.

So my question is: the `produces` attribute is used to narrow the mapping by the media types that can be produced by the mapped handler, not to declare the media types the mapped handler will produce, right? Then how should I return xml content in the condition of automatically serialized into JSON format? I guess I mess up the meaning of the content showing in the view with HTTP response body... Please someone explain to me nicely and patiently :"(

Comment: `@ResponseBody` only tells that the result is written in the body of the response **not** how it is written. How it is written depends on what the client accepts (XML, JSON, etc) a suitable `HttpMessageConverter` is then selected and the output written. So `@ResponseBody` has nothing (and all) to do with just JSON.

Comment: @M.Deinum `@ResponseBody` has nothing (and all) to do with just JSON. --> What is that mean? And please check this article out: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body#requestbody

Comment: That article is wrong. As stated `@ResponseBody` as the annotation implies returns the result of the controller method as the body of the response. The **how** (xml, json, excel, binary, .... ) isn't forced but, as stated, depends on what the client accepts (and what you support!). So if you support XML and the client requests XML it will be XML. If you support JSON and the client supports JSON it will be json etc. So as stated it doesn't enforce anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm so sorry :( But I want to clarify that response body mentioned above is equivalent to **HTTP response body** right? Sometimes I'm not sure if my interpretation is correct.

Comment: What else would it be? We are in the context of the web.